# How combine the data that are retrieved from two databases with reference to id?

Tags: dataweave

For better understanding, I provide two employee details here what I got as output

```
[
    {
        "shortlisted_at": "2021-01-25T01:33:56",
        "gender": "Female",
        "date_of_birth": "1977-09-18T00:00:00",
        "last_name": "sri",
        "interview_scheduled_at": "2023-01-24T21:42:53",
        "attended_test_at": "2021-03-17T20:17:56",
        "offered_joining_letter_at": "2020-12-13T03:43:43",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 1,
        "location": "North Jenniferfort",
        "date_of_hire": "2021-04-13T00:00:00",
        "applied_for_job_at": "2022-02-18T15:50:07",
        "first_name": "rama",
        "job_title": "Engineer, water",
        "email": "ellisjames@example.net"
    },
    {
        "shortlisted_at": "2022-05-19T02:28:55",
        "gender": "Male",
        "date_of_birth": "1977-09-18T00:00:00",
        "last_name": "Gonzalez",
        "interview_scheduled_at": "2023-01-24T21:42:53",
        "attended_test_at": "2021-03-17T20:17:56",
        "offered_joining_letter_at": "2020-12-13T03:43:43",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 2,
        "location": "North Jenniferfort",
        "date_of_hire": "2021-04-13T00:00:00",
        "applied_for_job_at": "2022-02-18T15:50:07",
        "first_name": "rama",
        "job_title": "Engineer, water",
        "email": "ellisjames@example.net"
    },
 {
        "SPECIAL_ALLOWANCE": 4848,
        "PT": 2517,
        "UNIFORM_ALLOWANCE": 3794,
        "HRA_DA": 18108,
        "BASIC_PAY": 15212,
        "TRANSPORT_ALLOWANCE": 3544,
        "SALARY_CREDITED_AT": "2001-05-01T00:00:00",
        "CTC": 38434,
        "PF": 1829,
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 1,
        "MOBILE_ALLOWANCE": 3417,
        "NETT_PAY": 12199,
        "ESI": 2375,
        "MEDICAL_ALLOWANCE": 1796,
        "EDUCATION_ALLOWANCE": 2285
    },
    {
        "SPECIAL_ALLOWANCE": 1296,
        "PT": 3631,
        "UNIFORM_ALLOWANCE": 1117,
        "HRA_DA": 15751,
        "BASIC_PAY": 15329,
        "TRANSPORT_ALLOWANCE": 1974,
        "SALARY_CREDITED_AT": "2020-07-01T00:00:00",
        "CTC": 41550,
        "PF": 4730,
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 2,
        "MOBILE_ALLOWANCE": 1973,
        "NETT_PAY": 16175,
        "ESI": 2667,
        "MEDICAL_ALLOWANCE": 3970,
        "EDUCATION_ALLOWANCE": 3631
    }
]
```

But what I want to get the output as

```
[
    {
        "shortlisted_at": "2021-01-25T01:33:56",
        "gender": "Female",
        "date_of_birth": "1977-09-18T00:00:00",
        "last_name": "sri",
        "interview_scheduled_at": "2023-01-24T21:42:53",
        "attended_test_at": "2021-03-17T20:17:56",
        "offered_joining_letter_at": "2020-12-13T03:43:43",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 1,
        "location": "North Jenniferfort",
        "date_of_hire": "2021-04-13T00:00:00",
        "applied_for_job_at": "2022-02-18T15:50:07",
        "first_name": "rama",
        "job_title": "Engineer, water",
        "email": "ellisjames@example.net",
        "SPECIAL_ALLOWANCE": 4848,
        "PT": 2517,
        "UNIFORM_ALLOWANCE": 3794,
        "HRA_DA": 18108,
        "BASIC_PAY": 15212,
        "TRANSPORT_ALLOWANCE": 3544,
        "SALARY_CREDITED_AT": "2001-05-01T00:00:00",
        "CTC": 38434,
        "PF": 1829,
        "MOBILE_ALLOWANCE": 3417,
        "NETT_PAY": 12199,
        "ESI": 2375,
        "MEDICAL_ALLOWANCE": 1796,
        "EDUCATION_ALLOWANCE": 2285
    },
     {
        "shortlisted_at": "2022-05-19T02:28:55",
        "gender": "Male",
        "date_of_birth": "1977-09-18T00:00:00",
        "last_name": "Gonzalez",
        "interview_scheduled_at": "2023-01-24T21:42:53",
        "attended_test_at": "2021-03-17T20:17:56",
        "offered_joining_letter_at": "2020-12-13T03:43:43",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 2,
        "location": "North Jenniferfort",
        "date_of_hire": "2021-04-13T00:00:00",
        "applied_for_job_at": "2022-02-18T15:50:07",
        "first_name": "rama",
        "job_title": "Engineer, water",
        "email": "ellisjames@example.net",
        "SPECIAL_ALLOWANCE": 1296,
        "PT": 3631,
        "UNIFORM_ALLOWANCE": 1117,
        "HRA_DA": 15751,
        "BASIC_PAY": 15329,
        "TRANSPORT_ALLOWANCE": 1974,
        "SALARY_CREDITED_AT": "2020-07-01T00:00:00",
        "CTC": 41550,
        "PF": 4730,
        "MOBILE_ALLOWANCE": 1973,
        "NETT_PAY": 16175,
        "ESI": 2667,
        "MEDICAL_ALLOWANCE": 3970,
        "EDUCATION_ALLOWANCE": 3631

    }
]
```

I tried map function. But it gives the null values of some details

Comment: Hi, Please use tripple ticks (```) for formatting jsons / code

Comment: For this specific problem, can you share what is the input that you are getting? Seeing only output does not help solving the problem. Also please elaborate the logic. Like on which field you need to merge the two payloads, and mention anything that is necessary to build the required logic

Comment: @SaiPrakash, it seems that the first list is the input and the second list is the expected output. That the input comes from a database seems not relevant, unless you are trying to do some database related operation in the solution? In general for DataWeave questions always show the input, expected output, what you tried and actual output.

Comment: I perform the select operation on MySQL and oracle sql developer the data which contains general details like first_name, gender, etc.,  is from the MySQL database and the data which contains salary details like basic_pay is from oracle sql developer. I used scatter-gather and perform a select operation on both databases then I combined using flatten function then I got the output separately as I mentioned. But I want to get the output in a combined format. Could you help me with that

Answer (score 0):

I'll make a guess that you want to join all the key-values of the items of the 1st list with matching `EMPLOYEE_ID` values.

For that we can use groupBy() to group the items. Then use `mapObject()` in each group to join its key-values into a single object using `reduce()`. Finally to convert each value of the object into an array we can use `pluck()`.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload 
    groupBy ($.EMPLOYEE_ID)
    mapObject ((value, key, index) ->  (key):(value reduce ($$ ++ $)))
    pluck ((value, key, index) -> value)
```